# Highcharts - Global configuration with common code and unique data & Headings

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts.

In single page, I have multiple `Area` charts with different data & titles and with same chart property configurations.

> **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0s2pkps0/1/)**

**Changes from Chart 1 to Chart 2, Chart 3** as below:

- Series Names
- Series Data
- Legend
- Tooltip data

Other than above, everything else is same...

How can I avoid writing repetitve code for `#chart-1, #chart-2, #chart-3` etc... and configure only above elements ?

**HTML**:

```
<div id="chart-1" style="height: 200px; width: 500px"></div>
<div id="chart-2" style="height: 200px; width: 500px"></div>
<div id="chart-3" style="height: 200px; width: 500px"></div>
```

**Global initialization**:

```
jQuery(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#fe5758', '#99cc03', '#33b5e6'],
        chart: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontSize: '12px',
                color: '#585858',
            }
        },      
        title: { text: null },
        subtitle: { text:null },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
......
```

**Chart 1**:

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart-1').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'area'
        },
        xAxis: {
            ....
```

**Chart 2**:

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart-2').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'area'
        },
        xAxis: {
            ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a variable for the options that are in common, like:

```
var commonOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    // ...
};
```

And then merge in the specific options for each chart like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(commonOptions, {
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
    // ...
}));
```

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ondkloss/nnsnggzd/) with legend, tooltip and series options.

Comment: **@Halvor Strand**... Hey **Genius**,  working like Charm :)

Answer (score 3):

How about creating function like `createChart`? And passing on variables? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0s2pkps0/2/

```
newChart('#chart-1', 'Date', 'Count', series_1);
newChart('#chart-2', 'Weekly report', 'Total views', series_2);

function newChart(container, xAxisTitle, yAxisTitle, series) {
  $(container).highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%eth %b'
      },
      title: {
        text: xAxisTitle,
      }
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: yAxisTitle
      },
    },
    series: series
  });
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. not sure what do you mean by `legend`, but you can add more arguments to the function, of course, but keep it simple if you can.